# Filtering an array in JavaScript with out using any built in functions or a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a min and a max.  Iterating through an array I need to remove all elements that are in between min and max. I cannot use any built in array functions like splice and the array needs to stay in the original order.  For Example the array [1,5,13,27,58] min = 10 max = 30 would return an array of [1,5,58].  I am looking for more of strategy of how to do this in N time complexity.  This question is for interview prep.

Here is the code I have tried,

```
function filter_range(array, min, max) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (min < array[i] && array[i] < max) {
      for (var j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        var temp = array[j]
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

var array = [1, 5, 23, 13, 59];
filter_range(array, 10, 30);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i])
}
```

Comment: @kevinternet, I just added the code I tried.  I did not get it to work

Comment: Is the array always going to be sorted?

Comment: @MikeC The array is not always going to be sorted

Comment: The code in you inner loop is swapping elements, not removing anything.

Comment: Possible approach: do a first pass where you replace removed values with `undefined` (or `null` or whatever), and then do a second pass where you defragement the array by shifting elements down to the left. This is still `O(n)` time, because there are a fixed number of passes, and each pass only handles each element once. (So it's `O(2n)`, which is `O(n)`.)

Comment: I just realized that since you do the swaps in a loop, it actually pushes the filtered elements to the end of the array. You could add a variable that counts the number of removed elements, then when the loop is done you can do `array.length -= removedElements;`. But this will still be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @apsillers How would you defragement the array without using a built in function?

Comment: @Aaron Keep an index `z` of the "end" of the defragmented portion, and each time you find a non-`undefined` array element on the second pass, move that element to position `z++`.

Comment: Loop through the array and fill in the undefined elements with the next defined element. Although I think you could do the same thing without the first pass, looking for elements that match the filter.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a callback function ? Because responses exist for your problem using callback function.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar that two passes are probably not necessary; it's just easier for me to think about as two completely separate loops. If you want the tightest code, you can do both operations (replacing and defragmenting) in the same loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull this off by merely overwriting the Nth element in the array with the next value that fits within that range, where N is the number of values discovered so far. Then set the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the array to the number of values you found.

```js
function filter_range(array, min, max) {
  var nextIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    var value = array[i];
    if (value >= min && value <= max) {
      array[nextIndex++] = value;
    }
  }
  array.length = nextIndex;
}

function test(arr, min, max) {
  console.log('Input: ' + arr.join(', '));
  console.log('Range: [' + min + ', ' + max + ']');
  filter_range(arr, min, max);
  console.log('Output: ' + arr.join(', '));
  console.log('');
}

test([1, 2, 3], 1, 2);
test([1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 4);
test([1, 2, 3], 0, 100);
test([1, 5, 13, 27, 58], 10, 30);
test([1, 13, 5, 58, 27], 10, 30);
```

Answer (score -2):

easiest way I can think of is moving the good values to a new array

```
  function run(){
  var a = [1,5,13,27,58];
  var b = [];
  var min = 10;
  var max = 30;

  alert (a);

  for (i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if (a[i]>max || a[i]<min) {
      b.push(a[i]);
    }
  }

  alert (b);
}
```

Comment: The title says you can't use a new array.